# Oracle External Tables with Unicode File Name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Could anyone help me with this particular error. I have a unicoded file name in hindi to which i am creating an external directory. The command for external directory creation completes without any error, however when i query the table it throws following error

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select * from EXT_TABLE_13868
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file येश.txt.tmp in EXTDIR_13868 not found [SQL State=99999, DB Errorcode=29913]
```

External Table Creation Script

```
CREATE TABLE EXT_TABLE_13868(cols..)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY EXTDIR_13868
ACCESS PARAMETERS (
RECORDS DELIMITED BY '\r\r\n' CHARACTERSET 'UTF16'
BADFILE EXTDIR_13868:'BAD.txt.bad'
LOGFILE EXTDIR_13868:'LOG.txt.log'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL)
LOCATION ('येश.txt.tmp')
)REJECT LIMIT 0
```

Database CharacterSet

```
 PARAMETER  VALUE
    NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
    NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
    NLS_CURRENCY    $
    NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
    NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
    NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
    NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
    NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
    NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
    NLS_SORT    BINARY
    NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
    NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
    NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
    NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
    NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
    NLS_COMP    BINARY
    NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
    NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
    NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
    NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   11.2.0.2.0
```

Please note, if the file names are kept in ANSI then the same process works without any issue even if the file content has unicoded data. It's the filename which is in unicode which is causing the issue.

Comment: the filesystem where the file should be located is..?

Comment: Can you check the `dba_external_tables` view to check if the file name has been correctly understood by the db?

Comment: The file system where the file is location on the same OS as the Database. I checked in dba_external_tables but i couldnt find anything specific to file names described in the table. @VincentMalgrat could you please be more specific on where i can find the file name in dba tables.

Comment: Sorry, It's in the `dba_external_locations` view, not the `dba_external_tables`.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat I just verified. The file names are stored properly, can't figure out why when querying it's failing. I am beginning to think it could be the instance configuration ? Btw i am using a default XE installation

Comment: Try using enclosing double quotes on your file name `"येश.txt.tmp"`

Comment: I've run a similar test on a 11.2.0.3.0 EE with an UTF8 file (named `येश.txt.tmp`, with an external table defined like yours) and it did work, so there shouldn't be an incompatibility here.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat thanks for confirming however it's still not working. I am trying to concentrate on charset. Currently my charset is following  PARAMETER VALUE
NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16

Comment: Can you please state more explicitly what the type of file system is and what operating system? On Windows, there are few types of file systems and Linux the amount is staggering. Not to be forgotten that each Linux file system can be configured differently. In our own software we store a lot of files using BFILE. For OS-independence we 've switched to just using US7ASCII readable characters. For instance, on Windows we've had problems with a TAB character in a filename and on Linux with some Unicode characters.

Comment: @GuidoLeenders i am using a windows 7 64 bit machine with Oracle XE. I have tried it on 3 different machines with windows 7 and Oracle XE and can reproduce the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Intriguing question. I can't reproduce:

```
create directory test_dct
as
'...'
/
create table test_table
( a varchar2(2000)
)
organization external 
( type oracle_loader
  default directory test_dct
  access parameters 
  ( records delimited by ',' characterset 'AL32UTF8'
    badfile test_dct:'test.bad'
    logfile test_dct:'test.log'
    fields terminated by '|' 
    optionally enclosed by '"'
    missing field values are null
  )
  location ('येश.tmp')
) 
reject limit 0
/
```

In file there is:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

And this returns neatly 6 rows:

```
select *
from   test_table
/
```

Works on 11.2.0.3 SE1 on Linux. You are running on 11.2.0.2 on Windows XP/7 and XE. The differences can be configuration, network, software or OS.

My configuration in v$nls_parameters is identical for nls_characterset and nls_length_semantics (which is not likely to cause problems but sometimes kernel developers at Oracle are just like people and they pick the wrong config setting). I don't expect a configuration problem to be the cause.

Network can not be an issue since the Oracle network drivers are not used anywhere in this scenario. So mappings do not apply.

Software versions are almost identical (11.2.0.2 and 11.2.0.3). I don't have 11.2.0.2 anywhere in my network available, from what I recall the only differences I noticed between 11.2.0.2 and 11.2.0.3 is that the dbms_metadata package was flawed and some minor tuning issues resolved. The initial release of 11.1 had some major Unicode bugs for specific queries, but nothing like that in 11.2. So I don't expect this to be the cause.

The editions XE and SE1 are not identical, but I don't expect an issue from it. Oracle Corp. needs to maintain a huge piece of software and they try to share the code as much as possible.

The best candidate is OS (or better said: relationship between OS and Oracle).

Recommended actions:

- Please check that you are using NTFS filesystem, which stores filenames as Unicode. FAT filesystems do not always handle Unicode well if at all.
- When I run in OS issues with Oracle, I like to debug the kernel a little. Similar to UNIX strace and similar, you can get more insight using sysinternals of the exact actions by the Oracle process. Use Process Explorer during the first open of the external file (available from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).)
- Use Filter to restrain the massive output to something readable and relevant.
- Compare this output with Notepad.exe or Winword.exe process explorer output when opening a copy of the same file with the same file name.
- Pay careful attention to the files being opened. There might for instance be a filename that is very similar, but has a chr(0) appended, a space or a rewrite of a Hindi character. When in doubt, use a hexeditor on the raw data from Proess Explorer. When starting on www.invantive.co.in we've had some issues regarding file names too.
- When this doesn't help, try to reproduce on a downloaded VMWare image with Linux and Oracle XE and post outcome here. Good luck!

Comment: @Guide Leenders. Thank you. I'll try to dig this further and let you know if i can identify the root cause.

Comment: Hi Amit, any news on the root cause following these actions?

Comment: I'm sorry @Guido Leenders, i have been traveling due to personal reasons. I still have not found the root cause for the issue. I'll update the thread as soon as i am back. Apologize for the delay.

Comment: hi @Amit was this answer helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?